# MongoDB (macOS Catalina Homebrew, without Homebrew)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, macos-catalina

**Installing MongoDB on macOS
Catalina Homebrew,
without Homebrew**

I have been working on these issues all day. I need your help.
I`m referring to 
https://zellwk.com/blog/install-mongodb/
https://betterprogramming.pub/installing-mongodb-on-macos-catalina-aab1cbe0c836

**1. Homebrew**

```
# Installs Homebrew
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
    
curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

How can I fix this,
I don`t know how to update SSL

**2.Run MongoDB macOS Catalina　From the Terminal without Homebrew**
Referencehttps://blog.londonappbrewery.com/how-to-download-install-mongodb-on-mac-2895ccd2b5c1

**- MongoDB setup**
Downloadfile https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.4.6.tgz 
Store here "/usr/local/mongodb"
Create.bash_profile (Vim export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mongodb/bin) inside User/username

**-Creating the Local Data Storage Location for MongoDB**

```
sudo mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
or
sudo chown (username) /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
```

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
```

Then run

```
mongod

mongod: command not found
```

I don`t know what should I do anymore...
please help me

Comment: 'curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html'

Answer (score 0):

I could find the way.

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

```
/bin/bash -c "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Then
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/
https://zellwk.com/blog/install-mongodb/